# How does Google's analytics.js authenticate the hostname?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm building JS-only plugin which will be implemented on multiple websites, each website having its own unique ID, which is passed to a Rails API along with some other data. My API will verify the hostname and ID provided by the JS plugin - but these things can of course be seen and used to fake impressions or events by anyone.

As far as I'm aware, there is no foolproof way of authenticating a website without an invisible, server-side key. That said, how does Google do it?

Analytics requires no server-side implementation, only an ID, which it of course checks against the hostname. Does this not mean that page views and events can be faked by a third party, and if so, why isn't it a prevalent issue?

Thanks in advance